# Average values by group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, group-by, average

I have two tables in my web app: one is for Donors (called "donors") and the other is for Donation Amounts (called "donations). When you click on a donor, you can see all of their donations.

I'm trying to average values associated with a particular date, for a particular charity. For example, if these records exist for Donor A:

```
        *Donor A*

   Date       Donation Amount
05/04/2013          30
05/04/2013          40
05/05/2013          15
05/05/2013          75
```

I'd like the system to also calculate and display that the average donation amount for 05/04/2013 was 35 and the average donation amount for 05/05/2013 was 45.

Currently I've tried using the group attribute in my donor model:

```
def self.average_donateperdate
    Donation.average(:donateamount, conditions: ["donor_id = ?", @donor], group: "donatedate")
end
```

This doesn't seem to work. Since I'm new to Rails, I'm not entirely sure whether this is the right way to do it or not. There are a few other posts that touch on this topic, but none that have helped me solve the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest syntax to do this is:

```
@donor.donations.group(:donatedate).average(:donateamount)
```

This will return a hash in the format `{ 'donatedate' => 'average donateamount' }`.

Naturally, this assumes you have a `has_many :donations` association on your `Donor` model.  A reusable method would look like:

```
def average_donation_by_date
  donations.group(:donatedate).average(:donateamount)
end
```

And you can now simply call:

```
@donor.average_donation_by_date
```

To see this visually, you can call this in your controller:

```
@average_donations = @donor.average_donation_by_date.to_a.sort_by(&:first)
```

And your view might contain something like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Average Donation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @average_donations.each do |date, amount| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= date.strftime('MM/dd/yyyy') %></td>
        <td><%= amount %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Reference

[Rails api - calculate grouped values](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-calculate)

Comment: last question, I promise! If I add a column like 'Age' to the table and want to have both average amount and average age per date displayed in my html table, what would I have to change in my model and controller?

Comment: What is an `age` for a donation?  And is this an attribute of your Donation model?

Comment: Or in general, if I wanted to add another column to the donor table and average in the same way I am averaging the donation amount, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: A single donor can't have an 'average' age - they only have one age, and the code you wrote for retrieving average donations is for a single donor.  Perhaps update your question with some sample data and sample output you want to see so I can better understand.  Even better, make this a separate question if involves a substantial change from the original.